# Gradle - How to get the latest code on Github even when dependency for latest version is set, but not getting it?

Tags: gradle, github, dependencies

I am not completely familiar with Gradle, so this might be an extremely simple question.

I have a dependency set on my `build.gradle` file to the latest version, however, when I look at the project's Github's `master` branch, there's new code that fixes issues that I would like to (more like **need** to) use in my project.

I have checked that the version of the dependency is the latest available on mavenCentral, and when I build the project (also tried running the Gradle builNeeded task) these changes that have been newly added in the Github repo, are **not** included in my project.

What can I do to be able to use the dependency's latest code on Github's `master` branch, even when adding the dependency's latest version does not do it?

Thanks for any help!

**Update**: Just last week the [dependency](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch) I was using released a new version containing the changes I needed, so this is no longer an issue for me. Thanks for the comments and replies.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might attract more people if you attach your `build.gradle`, link to the mentioned Github project, the version Gradle currently resolves and finally what you expect Gradle to fetch.

Comment: Thank you! I was working with easy-batch (https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch) version 5.2.0 at the moment, and just last week they released v.5.3.0 which has exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the version correctly: you would like to build your code with a dependency that contains all the code, including unpublished one.

If that's the case, then what you are looking for is Gradle [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/composite_builds.html), where the only strict requirements is that the dependency uses Gradle as its build tool.

If that is not the case, you will have to see with the library authors if they have a development version published somewhere that you can depend upon.